# Caching in JPA (Eclipselink + Dropwizard + MySQL)

Tags: java, jpa, caching, eclipselink, dropwizard

I have troubles with my queries returning stale database data, so I assume that it has something to do with caching. I absolutely do not understand what is going on and I would love to.

I have a database table Application mapped to an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_application", catalog = "something", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "Application.findById", 
    query = "SELECT a FROM Application a WHERE a.id = :id"))
  }
)
public class Application implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  ...

  @JoinColumn(name = "status", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private ApplicationStatus status;

  ....
```

I also have a REST service implemented in Dropwizard where I fetch these beasts:

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("/{id}")
public Application findById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
  return em.find(Application.class, id); // em is an entity manager
}
```

If I start my Dropwizard application and access this resource, my application gets returned properly for the first time. Then, if I go to the database and by hand change the application status value from "Accepted" to "Rejected" (a foreign key), and again access my REST service fetching the same application, it does not update the status attribute (my manual database changes are being ignored). If I shut the whole thing down and restart, the REST service gets the updated value and returns the entity properly (until I modify the database by hand again).

Here is my persistence unit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="to.rented_RentedToPMS_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>pms.core.entities.applications.Application</class>
<class>pms.core.entities.applications.ApplicationStatus</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rented?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="someuser"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="somepassword"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Without any results, I tried adding:

```
  <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

as well as fetching using NameQuery with hints:

```
setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache)
```

Can anybody help me and explain what is going on?

**EDIT:**

This seems to rectify the issue. But still, does it mean that I need to call refresh for each entity? What if I want to fetch all applications? Do I need to iterate through all of them and refresh? It seems very stupid to me, so I guess the answer is no...

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("/noauth/{id}")
public Application findById(@PathParam("id") int id)  { 
    Application a = em.find(Application.class, id);
    em.refresh(a);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to add to persistence unit (more info see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html)):

```
  <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

2) If (2) isn't work, try to add annotation @Cacheable(false) before Entity:

```
...
@Cacheable(false)
public class Application implements Serializable {
```

3) If (3) isn't work, run application to debug mode and set breakpoint in em.find(Application.class, id) or add logging in this line, if your application stop in breakpoint only first times, problem with Rest, if stop everytimes - with JPA.

**Update**: If em.refresh(a) help you, it's mean that you EntityManager isn't Stateless in you servlet, for example it's example Stateless:

```
 @Stateless 
 public class YourServlet {
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    public void enterOrder(int custID, Order newOrder) {
      Application a = em.find(Application.class, id);
      ...
    }
```

It's statefull:

```
 @Stateful
 public class YourServlet {
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    public void enterOrder(int custID, Order newOrder) {
      Application a = em.find(Application.class, id);
      ...
    }
```

Comment: (1) did not help, (2) did not help, and combination of (1) and (2) did not help. I added logging statement before and after em.find(). It gets printed each time I access REST, so it should be JPA.

Comment: I fixed my post, it's look like in your servlet EntityManager statefull and work with one transaction. You can try to change em stateless or open new transaction for every request

Comment: Hm, the stateless problem might be it, but truth to be told, I do not really know how to fix it. I am not sure how to turn the dropwizard resource into stateless---it is not clear to me where the @Stateless annotation would belong in the Dropwizard architecture: Dropwizard is built on Jersey. The resources are registered with Jersey on the application startup. This is also the place where I create my entity manager---I have it as a static attribute of the main application class, and retrieve it using a static getter in resource classes. Is this approach absolutely wrong?

Comment: Call em.clear() at certain points then as this is effectively the same thing as obtaining a new EntityManager.  With the shared cache turned off, all queries will need to get the data from the database after clear is called, allowing normal EntityManager usage and caching to resume.